# mysql statement for multi AND in mm table

Tags: php, mysql

i need some help for a mysl-statement. i have a table for "hotels" and a table for "pictogram". both are relatate with mm relation in table hotels_pictogram_mm. on the website the users can choose several pictogram in a search box. so i want to get all hotels which have for example "wellness" AND "free wifi". how must the sql statement be for this search.

following of course does not work:

```
SELECT *
FROM hotel 
LEFT JOIN hotel_pictogram_mm ON hotel.uid=hotel_pictogram_mm.uid_local 
LEFT JOIN pictogram ON hotel_pictogram_mm.uid_foreign=pictogram.uid 
WHERE 
pictogram.id = 3
AND pictogram.id = 5
```

thanks for help!
martin

Comment: Maybe try with OR: `pictogram.id = 3 OR pictogram.id = 5`?

Comment: OR is not the correct statement because the result would show hotels which have wellness OR free wifi. but i only need hotels having both.

Comment: The same field cannot have 2 different values so using OR is NOT the correct statement. Hence you need to check 2 different rows on pictogram at the same time when BOTH are joined to hotel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join against pictogram twice, once for each id:-

```
SELECT *
FROM hotel 
INNER JOIN hotel_pictogram_mm ON hotel.uid=hotel_pictogram_mm.uid_local 
INNER JOIN pictogram p3 ON hotel_pictogram_mm.uid_foreign=p3.uid 
INNER JOIN pictogram p5 ON hotel_pictogram_mm.uid_foreign=p5.uid 
WHERE p3.id = 3
AND p5.id = 5
```

You could join once and use count to check the number of matching ids from pictogram, but depends whether you want columns other than those in the hotel table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM hotel 
LEFT JOIN hotel_pictogram_mm ON hotel.uid=hotel_pictogram_mm.uid_local 
LEFT JOIN pictogram ON hotel_pictogram_mm.uid_foreign=pictogram.uid 
WHERE 
pictogram.id = 3
AND pictogram.id = 5
```

This query `will have empty set` since `pictogram.id = 3` AND `pictogram.id = 5`. CANT BE TRUE AT SAME TIME.Use `OR` instead.

So you should use

```
SELECT *
    FROM hotel 
    LEFT JOIN hotel_pictogram_mm ON hotel.uid=hotel_pictogram_mm.uid_local 
    LEFT JOIN pictogram ON hotel_pictogram_mm.uid_foreign=pictogram.uid 
    WHERE 
    pictogram.id = 3
    OR pictogram.id = 5
```

**Note** : Since you are doing LEFT JOIN on `pictogram` , and using `pictogram.id = 3` in `WHERE` it will act like `INNER JOIN`.

Insted you can do it like this

```
SELECT *
        FROM hotel 
        LEFT JOIN hotel_pictogram_mm ON hotel.uid=hotel_pictogram_mm.uid_local 
        LEFT JOIN pictogram ON hotel_pictogram_mm.uid_foreign=pictogram.uid
 AND (pictogram.id = 3 OR pictogram.id = 5)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is `id` for hotel, you can do self join to the result set , it self. This will work

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM
(SELECT *,hotel.`id` 
FROM hotel 
INNER JOIN hotel_pictogram_mm ON hotel.uid=hotel_pictogram_mm.uid_local 
INNER JOIN pictogram ON hotel_pictogram_mm.uid_foreign=pictogram.uid 
WHERE 
pictogram.id = 3) T1 INNER JOIN 
(SELECT hotel.`id`
FROM hotel 
INNER JOIN hotel_pictogram_mm ON hotel.uid=hotel_pictogram_mm.uid_local 
INNER JOIN pictogram ON hotel_pictogram_mm.uid_foreign=pictogram.uid 
WHERE 
pictogram.id = 5) T2 ON T1.`id`=T2.`id`
```

Hope this helps.